# New version 12 symbols are not highlighted by the syntax highlighter

Tags: feature-request

I've noticed that the symbol list for syntax highlighting doesn't include many symbols that are new in version 12. For example:

[image]

You can see that `Reverse` is highlighted correctly, while `SubsetMap` is not.

If possible, the list of symbols in the syntax highlighter should include all symbols in [this list](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NewIn120AlphabeticalListing.html).

If the syntax highlighting code is available somewhere I'm happy to make the pull request - I just need to be pointed to it

Answer (score 10):

**Note: Heavily updated**

I'm in charge of this. For the new version 12, I used last weekend to completely restructure the code and move it to a new repository:

- [Wolfram Language support for the Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/halirutan/WolframLanguage-Google-Prettify)

I spend a good amount of time to document how it works and to prepare examples and tests. The final highlighter script is either `lang-mma.min.js` or `lang-mma-alternative-regex.min.js` and the README explains the difference in detail.

If you clone the repository, you can directly try the highlighter by opening `JSHighlighter/index.html` locally. If you have some knowledge with the Chrome developer tools, you can also use [local overrides](https://www.afasterweb.com/2018/04/19/using-local-overrides-in-devtools/) to try it on the live StackExchange site.

It would be great if some other users could look over it and try it before I make a release. After that, we need to bug SE staff that they update the script for our site. We learned that their workload is currently high, so we should not expect a quick solution though. But we can ask.

Comment: I'll do this for you right now.

Comment: I expected nothing less :)

Comment: [Pull request in](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-Source-Highlighting/pull/8)